# Asp.net error on trying to connect with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection

I am trying to connect to a database which is an .mdb file from my web application on asp.net. This error comes up 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0  Data Source =C:\Users\KIKI\Desktop\ASP.net labs\Erg8\Erg8\ebookstoredb.mdb' provider is not registered on the local machine. The thing is that on my connection string I don't use version 12 but 4. I tried installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable which gives me the option to select version 12 when I set it the connection from the "Server Explorer" window but the error is still there. Any ideas? I have spent hours looking for a solution...
 Here is my connection string:

```
OleDbConnection constring = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\KIKI\\Desktop\\ASP.net labs\\Erg8\\Erg8\\ebookstoredb.mdb");
```

Also, I tested the connection when I set it and a message "Connection Succeeded" came up. The problem seems to be when I run the application on the browser.

Comment: You should have the .mdb file inside the folder of your ASP.NET application. You can use the `|DataDirectory|` substitution to avoid having the absolute path inside the connection string.

Comment: Yes the .mdb is inside my folder. I previously had it as Server.MapPath(~/ebookstoredb.mdb) but  the error was still there. I don't think it has to do with that. Thank you though..

Comment: Make sure the application pool your app is in has the Enable 32-bit applications option set. Sometimes this helps

Comment: Maybe check [these solutions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: @JohnWu I did all of these before posting here...This is so weird!

Comment: @Mark Fitzpatrick Where is that? You mean the platform in the Configuration Settings of Visual Studio?

Comment: No, the application pool that IIS uses to run applications has a bitness to it. Normally it's 64-bit by default, and that prevents 32-bit libraries from running and that can affect drivers as well.